# How to create a window looks like Tweetie Mac OS X app new post window

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I have some questions about this window:

[image: Tweetie]

- What type this window is (I've found that only "Textured Window" has rounded bottom corners)?
- Why it doesn't have a title? Could I add it?
- [How to add a label to the title (word counter)](http://iloveco.de/adding-a-titlebar-accessory-view-to-a-window/).
- [How to add a bottom bar?](http://iloveco.de/bottom-bars-in-cocoa/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a plain old `NSWindow`. It's not textured. You can set a title with `setTitle:` in code or the Title field in the IB inspector. Tweetie's window doesn't have a title because the developer chose not to give it one.

The bottom bar is created by setting the content border on the window. Look under the Size tab in the IB inspector. (Uncheck "Autosize" and put in a value.) You can also pick "Large bottom border" from the popup menu in that tab and have IB set it up for you.

You can add a label in Interface Builder. Just type "label" into the Library filter search box and it will come up.

Comment: Some uses of this window in Tweetie have a title. OP simply took a screenshot of an instance where it does not.

Comment: "You can add a label in Interface Builder." -- It's not a obvious question. I asked about the label in the right part of the window title (it shows "140").

Comment: Ah, sorry, misread. That's a bit more challenging. Basically, you'll need to look at the window's `contentView`'s superview. That should be the window frame. Then you should be able to lay out a label in the upper right corner of that view and have it appear in the title bar.